# How should I wrap up my engine?

Tags: javascript, web-applications

I'm creating a game engine, or more like a large library of useful classes and functions, for Javascript. I plan to use it both for some scientific simulations on the server side and on the client side, so the spectrum of functionality will be quite broad, but always it will revolve around a virtual world (a game, for example).

I'm not sure how to wrap it up, though. If I just provide all the classes, it would pollute the global namespace, which is quite bad. Can I just place everything inside one object, that acts as a namespace? Should the framework itself be a class that can be instanced?

If the later option is chosen, how do I handle classes inside classes (constructor functions)?

```
var Engine = function()
{
    this.someVar = 4;
}

Engine.prototype.Scene = function()
{
    this.entities = [];
    //What if the scene object needs some classes that are in the engine? How does it get it's parent engine object?
}

Engine.prototype.Scene.prototype.render = function()
{
    //"this" should now represent an instance of a scene. But how can I get someVar from the engine? How can I traverse up in the hierarchy of classes?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use what's sometimes called a "[revealing module](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript)" (... pattern). It looks like:

```
var Engine = (function($)
{
    $ = $ || {};
    var someVar = 4;

    $.Scene = function()
    {
        this.entities = [];
    }

    $.Scene.prototype.render = function()
    {
        // this function can access someVar just fine because of JavaScript's scoping rules
    }

    return $;
})(Engine);
```

This uses what's called an *immediately-invoked function expression* (hereafter referred to as an *IIFE*) to form a closure within the Engine object. Due to [JavaScript's handling of scope](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html), `someVar` is accessible to any function defined within the IIFE. The implication, however, is that no function can define it's own `someVar` if it wants to refer to the `someVar` you define in the IIFE.

The magic comes from the return statement. You can see that an object is returned, and within this object you must define anything you want to be "public".

The constructors, utility methods, etc. can then be accessed via `Engine.Scene`, which nicely namespaces your code.

As for the `$` argument, this is so that you can pass `Engine` to the function in each file, add some methods/properties/constructors (or create a new one if it doesn't exist) and then pass the return value to another IIFE for further expansion.

This is the method used in *many* popular JavaScript frameworks including [jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/intro.js), [dojo](https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/master/dojo.js) and [LimeJS](https://github.com/digitalfruit/limejs/blob/master/lime/src/lime.js)

---

scene.js:

```
var Engine = (function ($) {
  // this creates a new object if Engine is undefined in the 
  // invocation below, and keeps the old object otherwise.
  // alternatively: if ($ === undefined) { $ = new Object; }
  $ = $ || {};

  $.foo = "foo";
  $.Scene = function () {
    // blah blah
  }

  // Engine holds either a newly created object,
  // or the old one if it was already defined
  return $;
})(Engine);
```

sprite.js:

```
var Engine = (function ($) {
  $ = $ || {};

  $.Sprite = function () {
    // totally works
    this.bar = $.foo;
  }

  return $;
})(Engine);
```

You can then use them with something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var mySprite = new Engine.Sprite;
  var myScene = new Engine.Scene;
</script>
```

You can substitute `$` with whatever you like, `$$` is common, or you can be clever. It's just a placeholder for the global object you're adding on to.

Comment: And you could also make it AMD compatible to support libraries like requirejs

Comment: I know how this works, but I'm not using it because every class needs a separate file. I can't put a few thousand lines of code in one file.

Comment: Could you please create another code box and demonstrate the multiple files technique?

Comment: There are a number of specific ways to do it, but I've put up the method I use. You might also use a framework like closure or requirejs if you need explicit dependency tracking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need or even should organize your classes like that. Even though the Scene and Engine classes are related, the Scene class doesn't have to be a children of Render. Use a flat class hierarchy instead, that will be easier to maintain and scale.

Finally, you should indeed put all these classes under the same namespace so as not to pollute the global namespace.

```
// Define the namespace only if it doesn't already exist. That
// way you can split the definition of your classes in various
// files, without having to worry in which order they are loaded.
if (typeof gameEngine === 'undefined') gameEngine = {};

gameEngine.Engine = function()
{
    this.someVar = 4;
}

gameEngine.Scene = function()
{
    this.entities = [];
}

// Add a new function to define which
// scene the Engine should render:
gameEngine.Engine.prototype.setScene = function(scene)
{
    this.scene = scene;
}

gameEngine.Engine.prototype.render = function()
{
    // render this.scene
}
```

Comment: So you're basically suggesting the first option? Also, there is no renderer object, the `Scene` has a `render` method.

Comment: @Bane, yes I guess it's the first option, you can simply define a namespace and put all the classes under it. Ok if the `Scene` does the rendering then there's no need for that extra method. In general, the idea is to use setters, like in the example, to inject dependencies. It allows keeping the framework more flexible.